# MsBuild: Can I detect if I'm "inside" of an <MSBuild>?

Tags: msbuild

I would like to be able to detect if the current evaluation happens within an <MSBuild>, or it just happens "top level".
So smg like this:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MyProperty>Value if called from "top level" build</MyProperty>
    <MyProperty Condition=" '$(AreWeInsideOfAnMsBuildTarget)' == 'true' ">Value if called from &lt;MSBuild&gt; </MyProperty>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I can't touch the <MSBuild> task call itself, it is outside of my reach, like:

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="SomeExternalTargetICantTouch">
    <MSBuild ... />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

One of my own Targets gets executed 3x within 1 project build, I guess because 1x it gets executed "top level", and then 2x within <MSBuild> tasks.
I guess the <MSBuild> -s are called using different `Properties`, thus my Target gets reexecuted instead of skipped

Comment: Can your target be rewritten to be incremental and be skipped if all output files are up-to-date?

Comment: How can I do that? Could you please link me an example or a guide? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MSBuild doesn't provide a built-in property that indicates how the MSBuild project was invoked.

The [`MSBuild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task?view=vs-2022) task shares the list of already-built targets across the parent and the child builds so I concur with your assumption that something is being changed on each `MSBuild` task.

As described in the docs in [Incremental builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/incremental-builds?view=vs-2022) you could add `Inputs` and `Outputs` to your target. (But not all targets will have a clean in/out pattern.)

Comment: Thanks, the Target in question copies files, so I guess I can make it incremental